# Nuxt js - window or document is not defined

Tags: nuxt.js

I have seen many questions related to this topic. But none of them solved my problem.

I have a situation, where I've to check the `innerWidth` of the window, to check if the device is mobile or not using the `isMobile` variable.

```
<div v-if="isMobile" class="stores">
   <p class="text-uppercase text-muted mb-0 mt-4">
      ...
   </p>
</div>
```

Below is my script code. I'm checking `process.client` but it is coming as `false`. I don't know if I've missed something which I need to add somewhere *(maybe nuxt.config.js)*.

```
    data() {
      return {
        isMobile: false,
      };
    },
    mounted() {
      if (process.client) {
        console.log("Hello from the client!");
        this.isMobile = window.innerWidth < 768;
      }
      console.log('process', process.client); // Logs as false
    },
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with your code. It works as it should. Let me explain.

Do you see that text in the console `Nuxt SSR`? It means that the output below is the result of `console.log` executed on the server side, not in your client. If you look in your console a little bit below this `Nuxt SSR` block you should see another output - either `process false` or `process true` depending on your current width of the window.

Not convinced? Try to replace that code with this and I think you'll believe me.

```
created() {
  if (process.client) {
    console.log("Hello from the client!")
  }
  console.log("Hello from the server... and also the client!")
}
```

It should output this.

[image]

Maybe you'd like to replace the `created()` function with `mounted()` because `created()` is called on both the server side and client side. And `mounted()` is called only on the client side when that component/page gets mounted. So that you don't have to check if `process.client` is `true` on the server side. Which will always be `false` so it's unnecessary to do that check.

Comment: I have changed and checked under `mounted` as well, but I can't see any log from `Hello from client`